# Do interviewers treat interns rude all the time?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, human-resources, internship, new-hires

I received an invitation email for a next-day interview and the time scheduled was very bad which was at 12pm, I asked for rescheduling but the HR said they do not have any available slots throughout the whole month. When I attend the interview (through a video call), there was this man sitting on a table while the other man was playing with his phone.

No respect when I greeted them and straight away called me to introduce myself. The funny part is they don't want the self-intro to be anything related to my resume and want me to showcase my skill as an associate not as an intern because they have high standards. As I am not an expert in the field, I could only give them some theoretical statements and opinions. The way both of them insulted me with:" our position is mainly for xx major, and mostly for young boys, I am curious why the HR sent you here for an interview." Until now I am still angry with their attitude, they may think I was wasting their time but commenting on gender is very rude for me.

Comment: Understand everything you have said, but what outcome are you looking for here?

Comment: Depending on country, commenting on your gender is not only rude, but *illegal*. Can you add a country tag please?

Answer (score 15):

An interview goes two ways: You try to convince them to hire you, and they try to convince you to work for them. I'd say they failed the interview. No need to be angry. It may have been unintentional, but they told you everything you needed to know about the company.

Comment: This. OP dodged a bullet.

Answer (score 7):

They have had probably tens of interviews, so it's likely they are going to be frugal when it comes to niceties. Especially if they've had quite a few ill-suited candidates. It's not unusual for them to get right to the point.

Having said all that, it's completely unacceptable for them to be rude to you, and in addition, it's completely unacceptable to make what I would categorise as a sexist remark.

But, honestly, I don't think there is much that can be done.

If you wanted to push the the issue, you could certainly email HR, and explain that you think there has been some sort of mixup, as the interviewers were surprised by your qualifications. You could then also say that the interviewers expected surprise at your gender, and gave the impression that you gender would count against you.

If HR is risk adverse, the may decide to offer you a second interview, with different interviewers.

But as @gnasher729 pointed out, you have to really think about if you'd like to work at such a place.

If all you want to do is get some closure, I recommend posting an anonymous Glassdoor review and leaving it at that.